# Mapping frames based on motion

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, motion, opticalflow

I need to create 3 intermediate frames between two frames (prevImg, nextImg), I have found out the motion of each pixel using `calcOpticalFlowFarneback()` function in `opencv`

```
  calcOpticalFlowFarneback(gray1, gray2, flow, pyrScale, pyrLevel, winSize,
                           iter, polyn, sigma, method);
```

then I have created 3 intermediate frames by calling the function createNewFrame(), with following shift (func. argument) values 0.25, 0.5, 0.75

```
void createNewFrame(Mat & frame, const Mat & flow, float shift, int & c, Mat & prev, Mat &next)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < mapX.rows; y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < mapX.cols; x++)
    {
      Point2f f = flow.at<Point2f>(y, x);
      mapX.at<float>(y, x) =  x + f.x/shift;
      mapY.at<float>(y, x) =  y + f.y/shift;
    }
  }
  remap(frame, newFrame, mapX, mapY, INTER_LINEAR);
}
```

But I am not getting proper intermediate frames..
the transition from one frame to other is non smooth (flickering).
What is the problem in my code ? What I need to do to get proper
intermediate frames ? ?

Comment: interpolation between frames is an active research topic and getting good results is very difficult, particularly on motion/object boundaries. Anyway, your questions implies you are hitting problems earlier. If I understand your algorithm correctly, you are "moving" the pixels of the first image along the motion vectors. Is that correct? What do you mean with 'non-smooth'? Which parts of the intermediate frames do not give the correct result?

Comment: @user_12 can you give sample images? we might be able to have a better idea of what is wrong with the intermediate frames.

Comment: I have added my program in compilable form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be multiplying by your variable `shift`, not dividing by it.

Try replacing your double loop in function `createNewFrame` by the following one:

```
  for (int y = 0; y < mapX.rows; y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < mapX.cols; x++)
    {
      Point2f f = flow.at<Point2f>(y, x);
      mapX.at<float>(y, x) =  x + f.x*shift;
      mapY.at<float>(y, x) =  y + f.y*shift;
    }
  }
```

Comment: still there is a small amount of non smooth transition from one frame to other, what I need to do to resolve that..

Comment: Unfortunately, the optical flow estimated by calcOpticalFlowFarneback is not perfect. Did you try to visualize it, by setting `shift` to `1.` ?

Comment: I didnt try that...  is there any other method to achieve my aim ?.

Comment: is there any other function in opencv which gives more accurate results than calcOpticalFlowFarneback()

Comment: There are a few other functions for dense optical flow (see on the OpenCV documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/video.html)), you can check if one of them gives more accurate results. However accurate dense optical flow is still an active field of research, so it is likely none of them will give perfect results...